# How can I add two conditional filters to the same IEnumerable?

Tags: vb.net, linq, if-statement

How can I fuse these 2 If statements to make both my Droplist filters work together to filter the data?  I have 2 droplists (transfilter and Soortfilter) and I want to be able to select something out of droplist 1 and select other thing out of droplist 2 and then press filter and have it show the items that have been selected by filtering with *both* filters.

@ this point I have Return `View(query.ToList())` what only shows my filter items from Droplist 1

```
Function Index(transFilter As TransactieType?, soortfilter As Soort?) As ActionResult
            Dim query As IEnumerable(Of Pand)
            If Not transFilter.HasValue OrElse transFilter.Value = TransactieType.Beiden Then
                query = db.Panden
            Else
                query = db.Panden.Where(Function(p) p.TransactieType = transFilter.Value)

            End If
            If Not soortfilter.HasValue OrElse soortfilter.Value = Soort.All Then
                query = db.Panden
            Else
                query = db.Panden.Where(Function(p) p.Soort = soortfilter.Value)

            End If
            Return View(query.ToList())
        End Function
```

I was trying this but that didn't really work

```
Function Index(transFilter As TransactieType?, soortfilter As Soort?) As ActionResult
    Dim query As IEnumerable(Of Pand)
    If Not transFilter.HasValue And soortfilter.HasValue OrElse transFilter.Value = TransactieType.Beiden And soortfilter.Value = Soort.All Then
        query = db.Panden
    Else
        query = db.Panden.Where(Function(p) p.TransactieType = transFilter.Value And p.Soort = soortfilter.Value)

    End If

    Return View(query.ToList())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're setting `query = db.Panden` in the first part of both `If` statements.  When you're dealing with incrementally building up a LINQ query, always

1. Start with a base case.  In this case it would be `Dim query As IEnumerable(Of Pand)`
2. Add each additional filter directly to that base case using `query = query.Where`.

   ```
   Function Index(transFilter As TransactieType?, soortfilter As Soort?) As ActionResult
       Dim query As IEnumerable(Of Pand) = db.Panden
       If transFilter.HasValue AndAlso transFilter.Value <> TransactieType.Beiden Then
           query = query.Where(Function(p) p.TransactieType = transFilter.Value)
       End If

       If soortfilter.HasValue AndAlso soortfilter.Value <> Soort.All Then
           query = query.Where(Function(p) p.Soort = soortfilter.Value)
       End If

       Return View(query.ToList())
   End Function
   ```